# I have a problem with the initial configuration of Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Steps to reproduce the problem:

`$ yarn create nuxt-app nuxt-project1`

`$ cd nuxt-project1`

`$ yarn dev`

**This is the error:**

> No rules found within configuration. Have you provided a "rules" property?

Comment: You probably want `cd nuxt-project1` for step #2 though typically trying `cd yarn nuxt-project1` would result in _"bash: cd: too many arguments"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some rules to your `stylelint.config.js` file
for example: taken from the https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration website

```json
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    "block-no-empty": null,
    "color-no-invalid-hex": true,
    "comment-empty-line-before": [
      "always", {
        "ignore": [
          "stylelint-commands",
          "after-comment"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "declaration-colon-space-after": "always",
    "indentation": [
      "tab", {
        "except": [ "value" ]
      }
    ],
    "max-empty-lines": 2,
    "rule-empty-line-before": [
      "always",
      {
        "except": [ "first-nested" ],
        "ignore": [ "after-comment" ]
      }
    ],
    "unit-whitelist": [
      "em",
      "rem",
      "%",
      "s"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved simply adding `rules` property to `styleling.config.js`.

before

after

```
module.exports = {
  // add your custom config here
  // https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration
  rules: {},
};
```